# Achievement app in more languages Windows Phone

Tags: c#, wpf, xaml, windows-phone-8, resources

I have a question about resources in Windows Phone.
I want to make application with multiple languages ​​(English, German, French).
At the moment I have a page where you can select the language, and two resx resource files.
In the details page type controls have different text blocks and want to replace text text field depending on the selected language.
Currently available languages are given as a vector language = {"English", "German"} added a panel stack.

An example of a resource file:

English.resx file

Name                       ||      Value

< TextBlock x: Name = "XTextBlock" />       Product Name

German.resx file

Name                       ||                  Value
< TextBlock x: Name = "XTextBlock" />       Name des Produkts

Page selection languages:

```
     English checkbox check

     German     uncheck

     French     uncheck
```

When I turn on the setting and when save should give the name of the blocks to change depending on the selected language.
When you browse the entire application must, value language (English, French) to be maintained at all times until the user wants another language.
One solution, structure, any idea is welcome?

Thank you!

Comment: No.  No no no.  Go read this https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/apps/ff637522(v=vs.105).aspx

Comment: ok, thx, but how to start, when select one languages how do I acces my own resources?

Comment: Go research localization. Buy a book if you must.  Then create a prototype with a single label on it and localize it.

Comment: ok, I use Globalization, CultureInfo but how to set to maintains all time in the app changes

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One solution can be as follows:

1. **Page.xaml**

   ```
   < TextBlock x: Name = "XTextBlock" Content = "" x:Uid = "uniqueIdentifier/>
   ```
2. **Resources.resw**

Add in your project a folder named "strings". Add subfolders for each culture you need: en-EN, de-DE, fr-FR. In each subfolder add the *Resources.resw* file. As shown in image:
[image]

The file will contain each UI controls (from all pages) and the text value:

- for en-EN

Name: uniqueIdentifier.Content

Value: Product Name

- for de-DE

Name: uniqueIdentifier.Content

Value: Name des Produkt

3. **Let it choose the device language or change culture:**

Choose language, then:

```
var cul = "en-EN";//or "de-DE".....
var culture = new CultureInfo(cul);
        Windows.Globalization.ApplicationLanguages.PrimaryLanguageOverride = culture.Name;
        CultureInfo.DefaultThreadCurrentCulture = culture;
        CultureInfo.DefaultThreadCurrentUICulture = culture;
```

Comment: hy, thanks, but still i have a problem, first: 

-when add --  Windows.Globalization.ApplicationLanguages.PrimaryLanguageOverride = culture.Name; get that =>
The type or namespace name 'Globalization' does not exist in the namespace 'Windows' (are you missing an assembly reference?)

but in the top i added: using System.Globalization;you have one solution?

Comment: I think Windows.Globalization does not exist in windows phone 8.0 so cannot override when choose my language and text from my  textblock no change, one idea?

Comment: Use this: CultureInfo newCulture = new CultureInfo(cul);
            Thread.CurrentThread.CurrentCulture = newCulture; More info here: https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/apps/ff637519(v=vs.105).aspx

Comment: hi, i try that but here sets a new culture, ok that's sounds great, but how  I can access my resources and override some text in textblock?